# Will it affect my UK tier 2 ICT work permit visa if marital status is separated?

Tags: united-kingdom

I have applied for a Tier 2 ICT work permit 3 years visa from a reputed A rating Premium sponser from Chennai. In the marital status I have mentioned I'm separated since my wife and I are not on good terms. It has been more than 6 months since we spoke and I have a baby child. Will this separated status cause ECO to reject my visa? If they ask for clarification, what type of questions or proof might they ask for? I do not have any proof of documents that we are separated. I have attended VFS biometrics on 15th May with priority services and was told I will get the visa in 5 working days. But it's been 7 working days now and no reply yet, which makes me to fear that something has gone awry. Please assist with your valuable advice.

Comment: Can someone please help with your answers.

Answer (score 1):

No, your marital status will not affect your visa application. However if you should reconcile at a later time and want your wife to join you, or you want the child to visit or reside with you in the United Kingdom, it might affect *their applications*. There will almost certainly be an extra degree of scrutiny to determine how genuine your marital status is at that point.

Comment: Thank you so much.. fingers crossed..